# Module to Module DB relations

Tags: yii

In Yii framework v1.1.13

I have Module "A" that has model class "M1" which is related to "M2" in Module "B".

Now my question is, How to connect Foreign keys between the two models.

I want the correct reference to M2 in Module B

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'M2_property' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'B.M2', 'M2_id'),
    )
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to connect the way u have done let gii generate its code for relations . Only thing u have to do is import all your module files in config main.php for example u have two modules say M1 and M2 and models in each m1 and m2 u just import as shown below

```
 'import'=>array(
        'application.modules.M1.components.*',
                'application.modules.M1.models.*',
                'application.modules.M2.components.*',
                'application.modules.M2.models.*',
         ),
```

The two modules will be related to each other

Comment: sorry was writing a comment, your solution worked, first: gii doesn't generate Module's models relations, all it does is generating the Modules's ID with a basic skeleton (Yii v1.1.13, correct me if I am wrong). second: In any Module there is a function called "init" that import all Module's models and components, so the first thing I should have done is "Yii::app()->getModule('B');" to init the Module. thanks again

Comment: No gii generats its default relations

Comment: what I meant before i know your solution, that I have to generate Module from the Module link in gii, then generate normal Model from the Model link in gii (which here will generate the relations as if the Models were located in protected/models folder). then I have to move the Models and reconfigure their relations (that what I meant by gii doesn't generate Module's models relations) because I didn't think that by importing the models in the config file, the reference will be normal (normal like what gii give you :)).

Comment: and I still say gii don't generate Module's model relations, because after the import the reference will not include the Module's signature, it will Include the referenced model Immediately since it is now global. i.e. it's not about the Module, do you agree?

Comment: No u don't need to reconfigure their relations . the reference will be normal u leave as it is don't change anything to it just copy the models from protected/models folder and place it in respective modules models folder and import as shown above they will be related normally